# Xserver Permission Denied tty7

Tags: permissions, xorg, 16.04

I have a linux box with kodi and the following systemd script to start kodi at boot:

```
[Unit]
Description = kodi-standalone using xinit
After = systemd-user-sessions.service network.target sound.target network-online.target

[Service]
User = kodi
Group = kodi
Type = simple
PAMName=login
ExecStart = /usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/openbox-session -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt7
Restart = on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

This worked fine under Ubuntu 15.10 but after an upgrade this doesn't work anymore. The service fails to start

`Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas sudo[3644]:     kodi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/kodi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service kodi start
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas sudo[3644]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by kodi(uid=0)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas gpu-manager[3671]: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[1]: Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[1]: Started kodi-standalone using xinit.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas sudo[3644]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[3692]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user kodi by (uid=0)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[1]: Started Session 11 of user kodi.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas systemd[3692]: pam_ck_connector(login:session): cannot determine display-device
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Release Date: 2016-04-04
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-85-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Current Operating System: Linux rasnas 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic root=UUID=1bca803d-6ad4-4e76-bc0d-10d37e041d51 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Build Date: 07 April 2016  09:18:50AM
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:         Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:         to make sure that you have the latest version.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:         (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (==) Log file: "/home/kodi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Apr 24 17:30:19 2016
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Fatal server error:
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 7 (Permission denied)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]:  for help.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/kodi/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE)
Apr 24 17:30:19 rasnas xinit[3692]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Apr 24 17:30:23 rasnas hyperiond[853]: V4L2 Grabber: Signal lost
Apr 24 17:30:34 rasnas xinit[3692]: /usr/bin/xinit: giving up
Apr 24 17:30:34 rasnas xinit[3692]: /usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
Apr 24 17:30:34 rasnas xinit[3692]: /usr/bin/xinit: server error
Apr 24 17:30:34 rasnas systemd[3697]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user kodi`

So how can I fix this? Please note that everything worked fine using 15.10!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran in this error today. After some investigation, the solution is provided [by the Kodi how-to](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux). Chapter 5 says:

> As of Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), you need to install and reconfigure the package `xserver-xorg-legacy` instead.

It works fine on my rig.

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Rootless_Xorg
The legacy wrapper needs more configuration: Edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and add
`allowed_users=anybody`
`needs_root_rights=yes`

Answer (score 2):

Oke not really the best solution out there but changing the systemd start job to chmod `/dev/tty7` before launching kodi seems to "fix" it. If anybody has a better and more ubuntu way to go, please enlighten me :D

```
[Unit]
Description = kodi-standalone using xinit
After = systemd-user-sessions.service network.target sound.target network-online.target

[Service]
User = kodi
Group = kodi
Type = simple
PAMName=login
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 777 /dev/tty7
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart = /usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/openbox-session -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt7
Restart = on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please let us know what the root cause is when you find it. I hit the exact same thing!

Comment: In which file did you make this edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using systemd anyway, another idea that might possibly get it working is to get systemd to act as a proxy between X and root privileges.

This would require installing `libpam-systemd` so that `systemd-logind` starts working on the console properly (cf. [Debian 9 release notes about Xorg server no longer requiring root](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#x-no-longer-requires-root)), and to switch from using plain `xinit` to using the `startx` wrapper (cf. [Debian bug #801401](http://bugs.debian.org/801401)).

I don't know the specifics of this Kodi use case, but stumbled upon this question while researching the generic issue, so I figured I best write this up to help someone else connect the dots.